# Web architecture for "sharing" API calls between users

Tags: python, django, architecture, scheduling

I recently posted a question: [How to dynamically create and close infinitely running Celery tasks using Django Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926686/how-to-dynamically-create-and-close-infinitely-running-celery-tasks-using-django) . But Django channels seems to be a fairly niche area of development so I'd like to open up the question as a question about general architecture patterns.

I would ultimately like users of my application to tap into the same data streams dynamically.
I am creating a cryptocurrency application where users are accessing the same live price data.
It seems ridiculous that every user should have to request an API for the same information.

##### Scenario:

`Multiple users are receiving BTC/USD data by API request. How can I get this data and share it between users?`

This problem must have been solved countless times but I'm finding it very difficult to find the correct method for setting up a scalable solution.

Comment: Do you mean that you are making an API request to a third party, and then returning that result to the users? So that for every user request you have to make an api call to the third party?

Comment: @RobertKearns Yes exactly

Comment: I would suggest caching the value returned from the third party . Django has a built in cache framework, which works nicely with many different backends. Then set the expiry to be however long you should hold onto 'stale' data. When the data expires (no longer found in the cache), make the request and cache the result again.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm possibly overcomplicating things with the redis server and celery task manager system in the linked post- although I imagine I could still use redis for this caching. I will explore this some more, thanks